# Reducing code duplication between static methods/variables and multiple properties files

Tags: java

Let's say I have multiple properties files that are nearly identical

```
public class Env1 {

    protected static String PROPERTIES_FILE = "some/path1";
    protected static Properties props;

    public static String getPropertyA
    ...
    public static String getPropertyZ
}
```

e.g. I have 20 of these environment files, and all getPropertyA through getPropertyZ methods are identical except that the PROPERTIES_FILE is different for each of these environment files.

I have these nearly identical 20 environment files because they are each tied to 20 different enum types with slightly different properties.

And it's convenient to call these environment properties from anywhere in the code without having to instantiate them.

Is there a way to reduce this 20 fold code duplication without having to turn the static member variables to instance member variables?

Comment: Not sure I understand... How do you like to get some property? `Env1.getPropertyA(); Env2.getPropertyA()`?

Comment: @WaleryStrauch Exactly.

Comment: Don't use statics. Use only one Env class and initialize it with different properties file. Then use dependency injection, e.g. Guice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, you could write a single `Env` class that would encapsulate all of the properties manipulations and eliminate code duplication. Here's a skeleton:

```
public final class Env {

    public static final PropertiesHolder FIRST = new PropertiesHolder("path/properties1.file");
    public static final PropertiesHolder SECOND = new PropertiesHolder("path/properties2.file");
    ...

    public static class PropertiesHolder {

        private final String path;
        private final Properties properties;

        public PropertiesHolder(String path) {
            ...
        }

        public String getPropertyA() {
            ...
        }

        public String getPropertyB() {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then from your code you could use it like this:

```
Env.FIRST.getPropertyA();
Env.SECOND.getPropertyB();
```

I don't think that it's a great pattern to use (as I tend to use `static` only when it's really needed) but at least you won't have 20 almost equal classes.

`Env` can also be declared as enum with values `FIRST`, `SECOND` etc.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.